# How do I execute savehist for tcsh history if my machine froze?

Tags: macos, kill, tcsh

My MacBook Air froze all of a sudden:  the keyboard, trackpad and display are all unresponsive.  However, ssh works.

I have one `tcsh` session active.  **Which signal do I send to `tcsh` for it to gracefully quit, saving history prior to quitting?**

My tcsh does have all appropriate `savehist` already setup, i.e. if I were to type in `exit`, all history would be saved.  Perhaps there is even some way for a superuser to steal the terminal, and actually pass in the characters `exit\n` as if they were typed in on the virtual terminal by the logged-in user?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing `sudo shutdown -r +1`, then `exit`, through tcsh on ssh, and it seems to have worked.  The system didn't reboot (probably because it was already frozen) and continued responding for `ping6` as if it was still online, but ssh did stop working, and it would seem like tcsh within Terminal was quit out nicely, too.

After waiting for the userland shutdown to complete, I had to press and hold the power button for 5 seconds to actually reboot.

I'm not sure if the same result would have been achieved had I have skipped `shutdown(8)`.